# How can I change rows and columns order depending the viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5 is it possible to have these two different layouts depending on the viewport?

[image: what i would like]

I would like to avoid `display:none` and JS/Jquery tricks if possible.

I try to do this by using bootstrap 5 tools like below but it's not working on large screen:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-xxl-4 col-md-4 bg-primary">
      <div class="card">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-xxl-4 col-md-8 order-md-2 order-xxl-3 bg-success">
      <div class="card">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-md-12 order-md-3 order-xxl-2 bg-warning">
      <div class="card">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The results on large screen (it's working as expected on small screen with the code above) :

[image: The result with the code above]

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `display:none`? Bootstrap aligns things in rows and columns. Your supplied code clearly has the row/column arrangement to support "small screen" but you'll need a different configuration entirely to support large screen. A media query and hiding this/showing the larger arrangement may be your best approach.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @leigero. I would like to avoid display:none because the content of my card is retrieved by a request and I don"t want to downgrade the application's performance. If it's not possible, I will use display trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine 2 flexbox grids :

```css
.scrollable {
  max-height: 24px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row g-0">
  <div class="row g-0 col-12 col-lg-4">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-primary">1</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-success scrollable">2<br />2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-0 col-12 col-lg-8 no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 bg-warning">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks pour helping @Tom. I think it's great solution and I will explore that.